# Spark: convert to initial RDD after reduceByKey

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce, rdd

I have the following RDD representing sales data:

```
val rddSales:RDD[((String, String), SalesData)]
```

I'm trying to make a `reduceByKey` where a key is a String composed of a (saleType + saleDate) from SalesData.
Actually I want to filter out SalesData with the same saleType + saleDate, and then return the `RDD[((String, String), SalesData)]` without duplicates.

I've tried the following approach: first mapped the RDD to the structure where the key is (saleType + saleDate) and the value is the SalesData. Then called reduceByKey choosing the first occurrence of a record with a certain key.

Is it the correct approach? And how should map back to the initial RDD structure? After reduceByKey I have `RDD[((String), SalesData)]`

```
rddSales.map(rddSales => (rddSales._2.saleType + rddSales._2.saleDate, rddSales._2)).reduceByKey((a, b) => a)
```

Comment: does it matter which duplicates are dropped?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to drop duplicate rows based on some of the information in each row. Using the dataframe API would be easier in that case.

Comment: @JoelBerkeley it doesn't matter which duplicate is dropped

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you have a `RDD[((String, String), SalesData)]` and want the same thing without duplicates by saleType and saleDate. If so ...

What about using `(String, String)` as your key rather than converting it to `String` and back? then you can do the whole thing with `rdd.reduceByKey((a, b) => a)`

Note that because row order is not preserved, this will give you a non-deterministic answer

Comment: This is a good idea. But what if in the initial `RDD[((String, String), SalesData)]` the (String, String) part represents `saleLocation`, `sellerKey`? So after I make reduceByKey by `saleType` and `saleDate` how should I transform it back to the initial RDD state where (String, String) is saleLocation, sellerKey?

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a tempRdd[( rddSales._2.saleType + rddSales._2.soldDate, ((String, String), SalesData))] and then apply reduceByKey on tempRdd.
Later tempRdd can be optimised by .map() operation.